# How to cast template arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, casting, static

I'm trying to cast the argument of Type2 to Type. It's not compiling.

Specifically, I'm trying to compare items of two different types, and want to cast the second element y to (Type).

This is in C++

```
template <class Type, Type2>                             
Type larger(Type x, Type2 static_cast<Type>(y));
```

E: Clarity

Comment: Is this c++? Please tag your post with the programming language.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Please edit your question to include more details, including your language and some example code.

Comment: Will do now, thanks

Comment: Are you trying to declare `larger`, or to implement it? You cast in the implementation, not in the prototype. The code you show only remotely resembles C++.

Comment: Declare. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: 2 things: What is Type2; is this a template type or it is a class/struct? 2) If it is a template type use `class` before its declaration else remove it from the template declaration. Then check whether the types you are converting are they really compatible

Answer (score 0):

I think you want do that static casting inside the function.  For example:

```
    template <class Type, Type2>  
    Type larger(Type x, Type2 y) {
        Type ycasted = static_cast<Type>(y);
        //compare x and ycasted
    }
```

However, it's possible that I misunderstood your question.  Hope this helps.